# Angular (2+) Component Structure and Design - best practices

Tags: angular, architecture

This is an architectural design question.

I have a mySQL table called X. 
And I have CRUD operations on it from an angular 2+ front-end.

To kick things off, I created a component which I happened to call `create-new`. This guy now runs on `/create-new` route.

But, as I developed, this create-new component ( with its .ts, .html & .css friends ) has become quite versatile to be able to handle, not just the create-new ( hence insert ) situation, but also the update.

This update can work not only right-after a create-new operation, (working with the newly inserted ID ) to allow the immediate updates to the newly created record, BUT ALSO can work with loading the data of another record to offer its update form.

So, naturally, this /create-new route has now become able to handle  param based requests such as /create-new/?action=edit&rec_id=10

And I like the fact that the original create-new code base was VERY EASILY stepped up to this capability. Now that insert, update operations are done, one cannot help but think, well, why don't I add the DELETE, LIST-VIEW, and  DETAIL-VIEW functionalities and be done with it. And that's where the architectural design question comes into mind that requires picking the experienced brains.

The pro's of this approach, I've got one component, which maps to one single folder, one single .ts, .html, .css and the server side .php page that is perfected to work with that table X. This makes it super easy to duplicate this functionality to get ourselves another set that is ready to take care of all the CRUD needs on say table Y with very little adjustments over the cloned-base.

I know the common pattern is to have one component for create-new, one for view-record, one for view-list on and on.

My question is the following: Does the approach of this do-it-all (that I just described above ) is an absolute NO-NO-APPROACH in all cases?

Or, can we say that hey, it is not all that of a big deal, and in fact, it could be the RECOMMENDED-APPROACH depending on the case?

If it is to OK to adapt this consolidated approach, I would just change the name create-new with manage-X and be done with it. Then the next guy would be named as manage-y and so on. I do realize that with this approach, the HTML part may get more sensitive to this do-it-all style. In this case, I will have to deal with a longer .HTML file (which will not only host the add-edit-form that talks to the table X but also the view-list and view-detail situations showing records from the table X. But that's a limitation that I can live with.

Again, back to the question..

Should this approach be never ENGAGED in? 
or there are cases where it warrants that it should be the way to go?

If it is OK to build components like this, what would be the main criteria to decide to go for this consolidated approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually style guides that says one should not do that but quite the opposite. Components should be as small as possible and follow single responsibility principle.

from docs:

> Apply the single responsibility principle (SRP) to all components,
>   services, and other symbols. This helps make the app cleaner, easier
>   to read and maintain, and more testable.

ref:https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility

Comment: So, that's for sure... an `absolute NO-NO-APPROACH in all cases`. Right?

Comment: from my experience, and from official guides (at least the way i read them) - absolute no no. i cannot think of a single reason why would anyone want to do it that way (other than masochistic reasons, of course :) ).